# Percent Encoding Reserved Characters

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Reserved_characters) lists several reserved characters that I am trying to replace in a string with their percent encoding. The characters are:

| Character | Encoding |
| --- | --- |
| ! | %21 |
| # | %23 |
| $ | %24 |
| % | %25 |
| & | %26 |
| ' | %27 |
| ( | %28 |
| ) | %29 |
| * | %2A |
| + | %2B |
| , | %2C |
| / | %2F |
| : | %3A |
| ; | %3B |
| = | %3D |
| ? | %3F |
| @ | %40 |
| [ | %5B |
| ] | %5D |

My batch script is reading in input from a user and then outputting a string where the reserved characters have been replaced by a their percentage encoded value.

The issue is some characters are not being read in, and other characters do not work when trying to percentage encode them.

My code is

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p pass=Enter pass: 

@REM Do % first so it doesn't replace all the new %
set "pass=!pass:%%=%%25!"

@REM Not working - set "pass=!pass:!=%%21!"
set "pass=!pass:#=%%23!"
set "pass=!pass:$=%%24!"
set "pass=!pass:&=%%26!"
set "pass=!pass:'=%%27!"
set "pass=!pass:(=%%28!"
set "pass=!pass:)=%%29!"
@REM Not working set "pass=!pass:*=%%2A!"
set "pass=!pass:+=%%2B!"
set "pass=!pass:,=%%2C!"
set "pass=!pass:/=%%2F!"
set "pass=!pass::=%%3A!"
set "pass=!pass:;=%%3B!"
@REM Not working set "pass=!pass:==%%3D!"
set "pass=!pass:?=%%3F!"
set "pass=!pass:@=%%40!"
set "pass=!pass:[=%%5B!"
set "pass=!pass:]=%%5D!"

echo %pass%
pause
```

And I'm testing with `Test ! # $ % ' ( ) * + , / : ; = ? @ [ ]`.

The `!` in the text doesn't seem to be read into the string and I had to comment out three character conversions as they didn't work.

How can I make it so it does read the ! in?
How can I escape the 3 commented out characters so that all reserved characters are converted to their percentage encode?

Comment: Replace `echo %pass%` by `echo(!pass!`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "pass=Enter pass: "
echo !pass: =   !

rem Standard cases
for %%a in ("%%=25" "#=23" "$=24" "&=26" "'=27" "(=28" ")=29" "+=2B"
                    ",=2C" "/=2F" ":=3A" ";=3B" "@=40" "[=5B" "]=5D" ) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims== eol=" %%x in (%%a) do (
      set "pass=!pass:%%x=%%%%y!"
   )
)

rem First two special cases
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "pass=%pass:!=[21]%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "pass=!pass:[21]=%%21!"
set "pass=!pass:?=%%3F!"

rem Last two special cases
:star
for /F "tokens=1* delims=*" %%x in (" !pass! ") do (
   if "%%y" neq "" (
      set "pass=%%x%%2A%%y"
      set "pass=!pass:~1,-1!"
      goto star
   )
)
:equal
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%x in (" !pass! ") do (
   if "%%y" neq "" (
      set "pass=%%x%%3D%%y"
      set "pass=!pass:~1,-1!"
      goto equal
   )
)

echo %pass%
```

Example:

```
Enter pass: Test ! # $ % & ' ( ) * + , / : ; = ? @ [ ]
Test   !   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]
Test %21 %23 %24 %25 %26 %27 %28 %29 %2A %2B %2C %2F %3A %3B %3D %3F %40 %5B %5D
```

Comment: Nice one! What happens if there are two consecutive `**` or `==`?